# Trying to use regex in bash for a specific word in a column uusing bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk

My file is like this -

```
dog_xyz123
cat_xyz_lm
sun_xyz-hi
moon_xyzabc
```

Now I want to keep only the lines which have `xyz` completely. What this means is any string with `_` and `-` along with `xyz` is allowed and even if there are numbers attached, it is fine. Just that `xyz` should not be a substring of another letter. That would mean that `xyzabc` would not be allowed nor would `abcxyz`.

What I have tried is as follows :

```
 awk 'match($1,/[-_]?xyz[-_][A-Za-z_0-9-]+/) {print $1}' filename
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `grep` with pcre

```
$ cat ip.txt 
dog_xyz123
xyz4
ABCxyz
abc_Xyz-123
cat_xyz_lm
sun_xyz-hi
xyz
moon_xyzabc
2xyz

$ grep -P '(?<![A-Za-z])xyz(?![A-Za-z])' ip.txt 
dog_xyz123
xyz4
cat_xyz_lm
sun_xyz-hi
xyz
2xyz
```

- `xyz` pattern to match
- `(?<![A-Za-z])` negative lookbehind - pattern cannot have letter before it
- `(?![A-Za-z])` negative lookahead - pattern cannot have letter after it

For case-insensitive version, like when `Xyz`, `xYz`, etc are also valid matches

```
$ grep -iP '(?<![a-z])xyz(?![a-z])' ip.txt 
dog_xyz123
xyz4
abc_Xyz-123
cat_xyz_lm
sun_xyz-hi
xyz
2xyz
```

- `-i` case-insensitive matching

Comment: only this answer seems to cover all test cases. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
grep -e "[_-]\d*xyz/d*[_-]" <infile>
```

Which should print the lines you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that:

```
grep -E '^(.*[^A-Za-z])?xyz([^A-Za-z].*)?$'
```

It will return all lines that contain `xyz` when it's not preceded or followed by a letter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
awk '/_xyz-/' file
sun_xyz-hi
```

Answer (score 0):

With that input all you need is:

```
awk -F'[-_]' '$2=="xyz"' file
```

If that's not what you need then edit your question to include more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

*any string with `_` and `-` along with `xyz` is allowed and even if there are numbers attached, it is fine* - - *`xyz` should not be a substring of another letter*, ie. `xyz` surrounded by anything but letters, including the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`) of record:

```
$ grep "\(^\|[^a-zA-Z]\)xyz\([^a-zA-Z]\|$\)" foo
dog_xyz123
cat_xyz_lm
sun_xyz-hi
```

Modifying your awk solution to support this:

```
awk 'match($0,/(^|[^a-zA-Z])xyz([^a-zA-Z]|$)/ {print $0}' foo
dog_xyz123
cat_xyz_lm
sun_xyz-hi
```